# Nuxt 3 - resolver.resolveModule is not a function

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to configure `style-resources` and use some variables globally in fresh Nuxt 3 project but when I am passing some options to nuxt.config file I am getting this error:

`Cannot start nuxt:  resolver.resolveModule is not a function`

My dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt3": "latest",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.43.4"
  }
```

nuxt.config.js

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['~/assets/main.scss'],
  buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],
  styleResources: {
    scss: ['./assets/variables.scss'],
  },
});
```

I am using this library:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module

I know Nuxt 3 is still in Beta release but maybe someone faced this issue already or knows different way to apply global resources

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think that module is supported in Nuxt3. Adding this to nuxt.config worked for me:

```
vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                scss: {
                    additionalData: '@import "@/assets/scss/variables.scss";',
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you! I can't seem to find anything about this in their documentation. I've spent the last hour trying to get this to work

Comment: Can u show, how to do it for stylus?

Comment: any way to do this with Nitro?